# I am getting error like [Error] cannot convert '__complex__ int' to 'int' in assignment

Tags: c++

here is my code and I amgetting error cannot convert '**complex** int' to 'int' in assignment

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Write your code here
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    int res=0;
  
    for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
   res = 3i+2;

    }
      cout <<res;
}
```

Comment: With the right namespace imports, `3i` is a [complex literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i). Without, it should be a syntax error. Need elaboration on what you're trying to do if not that - multiplication? And what's the point of that loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is syntactically incorrect.
I assume the correct code is this-->

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// Write your code here
int x;
cin>>x;
int res=0;

for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
     res = 3*i+2;
}
   cout <<res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't understand what are you trying to do but     res=3i+2      is wrong as you should write     res=3*i+2      to multiply if that's what you are trying to do